# how to fetch data from service in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using this api's for my demo app (https://restcountries.eu/)

API url is this
https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

But I am not able to fetch data from service in angular

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3jpqrc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
constructor(private dataservice : DataService){

     this.dataservice.fetchDataThroughPromise().subscribe(()=>{
      console.log('s')
    })
  }
```

service code

```
 fetchDataThroughPromise(){
    return this.http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all',
      {
        headers :new HttpHeaders({
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        })
      });
  }
```

see error when created project using angular cli

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove:

```
    headers :new HttpHeaders({
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    })
```

Final code:

```
fetchDataThroughPromise() {
  return this.http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
}
```

Comment: yes your anwer work correctly in online editor .but why it is not working when I create project using angular cli

Comment: see my changes i got this error on my local project

Comment: I have created a new project with angular-cli. I have done your request in the app.component.ts and its works

Comment: hmm ..i found my issue i added `memolize libraray`